# weird RSpec behavior when runnig controller spec and retrieving last record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rspec, rspec-rails

this is log from debugger when I run my *PostsController* spec on **create** action. I'm not changing or manipulating any  db records during runtime with console so this is no special case.

```
(rdb:1) p Post.last
#<Post id: 2, author_id: 3, title: "My ultra cool post", content: "Lorem ipsum", deleted_at: nil, created_at: "2012-08-31 09:21:20", updated_at: "2012-08-31 09:21:20", published_at: nil, display_from: nil>

(rdb:1) p Post.all
[#<Post id: 2, author_id: 3, title: "My ultra cool post", content: "Lorem ipsum", deleted_at: nil, created_at: "2012-08-31 09:21:20", updated_at: "2012-08-31 09:21:20", published_at: nil, display_from: nil>, 
 #<Post id: 3, author_id: 2, title: "My ultra cool post", content: "Lorem ipsum", deleted_at: nil, created_at: "2012-08-31 09:21:20", updated_at: "2012-08-31 09:21:20", published_at: nil, display_from: nil>]

(rdb:1) p Post.last
#<Post id: 2, author_id: 3, title: "My ultra cool post", content: "Lorem ipsum", deleted_at: nil, created_at: "2012-08-31 09:21:20", updated_at: "2012-08-31 09:21:20", published_at: nil, display_from: nil>
```

So Post.all shows that post 3 exist but Post.last not

but when I do

```
(rdb:1) p Post.all.last
#<Post id: 3, author_id: 2, title: "My ultra cool post", content: "Lorem ipsum", deleted_at: nil, created_at: "2012-08-31 09:21:20", updated_at: "2012-08-31 09:21:20", published_at: nil, display_from: nil>
```

Controller file:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post.author = current_user
    @post.save
    debugger # this is where I'm debugging
    respond_with @post
  end
end
```

- this behavior works in develompent code correctly

the only implication for me is that in my spec I'll do

```
 response.should redirect_to Post.all.last
```

insted of

```
 response.should redirect_to Post.last
```

I know that in Ralis there are some cases where Active Record triggers call before DB is ready ?  but in this case the ActiveRecord actually know about existance of this record with .all call but not with .last, so this is just weird

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is quite logic: default order is based on `created_at`, and your objects both have the same `created_at` date time.

So the database has to make a (random) choice.

---

Actually, I just read dthe default order depends on the database you're working with. To be sure you get what you expect use a `default_scope`, for instance:

```
default_scope order('id ASC')
```

Comment: well, it turns out you are actually right, I had *default_scope order: ('published_at DESC')* in my post model and it was causing this problem. Thx +1